# Difficulties installing ITK

Tags: installation, itk

So I am using Cmake and Mingw 32 on a windows 7 machine to install ITK 4.2.1.  However, I am getting the following error.  I have attempted to google the answer but have not found anything.  Any and all help would be very much appreciated!

```
[  1%] Building CXX object Modules/ThirdParty/VNL/src/vxl/vcl/CMakeFiles/itkvcl.
dir/vcl_deprecated.cxx.obj
g++.exe: error: /wd4244: No such file or directory
mingw32-make[2]: *** [Modules/ThirdParty/VNL/src/vxl/vcl/CMakeFiles/itkvcl.dir/v
cl_deprecated.cxx.obj] Error 1
mingw32-make[1]: *** [Modules/ThirdParty/VNL/src/vxl/vcl/CMakeFiles/itkvcl.dir/a
ll] Error 2
mingw32-make: *** [all] Error 2"
```

Thanks,

Matt

Comment: Can you provide the link you followed to install ITK, so that i can also repeate the same process you followed.

Comment: You appear to have visual studio flags being sent to g++. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/thxezb7y.aspx Did you pick mingw makefiles for your generator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you remove VNL option (if it is not needed in your project) while configuring ITK this error may be solved.

If you want to build with MSVC this link will surely help you

http://qtitkvtkhelp.blogspot.in/2012/11/itk-installation-for-msvc.html

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest installing Visual Studio (VS) 2013 Express edition and using it to build ITK. I have been using ITK since 2008 and I believe VS is the intended compiler/IDE for ITK developers on Windows.

If you have a look at the ITK Dashboard, they have several nightly builds for VS, but I do not see MinGW for Windows anywhere: https://open.cdash.org/index.php?project=Insight